# MySQL Server wont start in MAMP - No current solutions work

Tags: mysql, mamp

I've just installed and opened MAMP for the first time on a Mac 10.12.6 (Sierra). I've set a new root folder, set the ports to the default 8888 & 8889, and when I hit "Start Servers", nothing happens. I don't get any kind of error message, the loading wheel just spins then stops. The Apache Server light comes on, but the MySQL server remains empty/blank, and the "Open Webstart page" option is still greyed out.

1. Typing killall -9 msqld (with and without sudo) into Terminal returns "No matching processes were found"
2. Running on ports 80 & 3306 doesn't work, nor does 3307
3. ***There is no ib_logfile for me to delete in the Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ folder.*** There are only 2 folders and a "mysql_upgrade_info" file. I tried deleting that and it didn't help
4. ^ There also isn't a MAMP folder in my Library/Application Support, just in case that's suggested
5. I uninstalled & reinstalled MAMP and that also did nothing

Here is my Apache Error log, in case anyone needs this to help

```
[Sun Dec 10 23:12:59 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 10 23:12:59 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 10 23:12:59 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 7201)
[Sun Dec 10 23:12:59 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.8 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 23:13:12 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 10 23:13:16 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 10 23:13:16 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 10 23:13:16 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 7318)
[Sun Dec 10 23:13:16 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.8 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 23:14:42 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 10 23:14:44 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 10 23:14:44 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 10 23:14:44 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 8186)
[Sun Dec 10 23:14:44 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.8 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 23:17:52 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 10 23:17:54 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 10 23:17:54 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 10 23:17:54 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 9256)
[Sun Dec 10 23:17:54 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.8 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Dec 10 23:18:27 2017] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Dec 10 23:18:29 2017] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Dec 10 23:18:29 2017] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Dec 10 23:18:29 2017] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 9736)
[Sun Dec 10 23:18:29 2017] [notice] Apache/2.2.32 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.13 PHP/7.1.8 mod_ssl/2.2.32 OpenSSL/1.0.2j DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.24.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on same version of OSX, tried the same fixes, nothing worked so had to delete MAMP and install old version (3.5.2) -  https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/older-versions/

Not an ideal solution, but I've got MAMP running again.